# NextJS: Is there a way to use i18n locale detection without applying sub-path routing?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, server-side-rendering, i18next

So i implemented Next's i18n routing in my project (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection), and now i can access the automatically detected locale in getServerSideProps props, which is great, but now every route of my app is pre-fixed with /en, /es, etc.

Is there a way to still detect the locale without applying the pre-fixes to all my routes?

Ex. if i create a new /blog page, i want to still detect the locale in the getServerSideProps props, but without it becoming a /es/blog route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hint at how this might be achieved in this part of the docs:

[image]

Later, on the same page, they show you how to stop a page from being generated for a particular locale:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
  // You can use any data fetching library
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts?locale=${locale}`)
  const posts = await res.json()
 
  if (posts.length === 0) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
 
  // By returning { props: posts }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but if you're serving all your pages on your default locale (which doesn't apply a subpath) and don't generate all the pages for other locales this should solve your issue i.e. you can detect the locale using `context` but choose not to generate the sub-path pages.